# Table design: Keeping track of Companies that can be Buyers and/or Suppliers

Tags: ms-access

I would like to get help with my tables design. Basically what I want to create is a table with invoices. Each invoice has a supplier and buyer. Normally I would create separate tables with buyers and another table with suppliers.
However, in my case the buyer can be sometimes a supplier. So I thought to create only one table with all companies. (buyer and supplier fields are related to company id)

**Problem**: This however creates duplicate rows when tying to pull invoice details and suppliers and buyers. 

If I go the way of creating separate tables for suppliers and buyers, I end up with 2 tables containing same records for some companies (since buyer can be sometimes a supplier), which I do not want. 

**Question**: What is the best way of designing/maintaining tables in such situations? Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the approach you show in your question. In fact, that can be a very good way to do it if you have additional attributes that relate specifically to a Supplier or a Buyer, e.g.,

- The contact information may be different for the two roles at the same company. With suppliers you would probably contact the Accounts Receivable department, while with Buyers you would probably contact Accounts Payable. So, you can maintain the two different contacts (name, phone, email) in each of the [Supplier] and [Buyer] tables.
- Perhaps you want to maintain a Rating for suppliers, say, 1 = "Preferred Supplier", 2 = "Regular Supplier", 3 = "Supplier of Last Resort". That attribute would go in the [Supplier] table. (You could also do that for buyers.)

An example of your tables might be something like this:

[Company]
company_id - AutoNumber, Primary Key
company_name - Text(255)
city - Text(255)
main_phone - Text(255)
...

[Supplier]
company_id - Long Integer, Primary Key, related to [Company].[company_id]
rating - Integer
contact_name - Text(255)
contact_phone - Text(255)
contact_email - Text(255)
...

[Buyer]
company_id - Long Integer, Primary Key, related to [Company].[company_id]
rating - Integer
contact_name - Text(255)
contact_phone - Text(255)
contact_email - Text(255)
...

[Invoice]
invoice_id - AutoNumber, Primary Key
supplier_id - Long Integer, related to [Supplier].[company_id]
buyer_id - Long Integer, related to [Buyer].[company_id]
invoice_date - Date/Time
...

Answer (score 0):

What I did, was instead of creating more tables, I created 2 queries - one for suppliers and another for buyers. Then third query combined 2 previous queries together. This way, I can maintain all companies from one table. Not sure if this approach has any caveats though

Comment: One caveat would be that you can create a Relationship between the [Invoice] table and the [Supplier] query but it cannot enforce Referential Integrity. You also don't need a UNION query to merge the [Buyer] and [Supplier] queries since you can query the [Company] table directly.